# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

This question is ask many times but there are no answer to solve my problem. I am new android developer so please give e reply of my problem. My problem is that when i start the LocSettingsActivity to find the location and try to putStringValue CITY then Exception occurd 
Logcat error is :

```
    09-09 14:54:46.353 10099-10099/com.psadi.psad.TSGS E/PSAD: Exception occurd    ->  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.psadi.psad.TSGS.preferences.AppPreferences.putStringValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
09-09 14:54:46.353 10099-10099/com.psadi.psad.TSGS W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.psadi.psad.TSGS.preferences.AppPreferences.putStringValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
09-09 14:54:46.354 10099-10099/com.psadi.psad.TSGS W/System.err:     at com.psadi.psad.TSGS.LocSettingsActivity.getAddress(LocSettingsActivity.java:289)
        at com.psadi.psad.TSGS.LocSettingsActivity.callLocationGpsTracker(LocSettingsActivity.java:252)
        at com.psadi.psad.TSGS.LocSettingsActivity.locationEnabled_or_Not(LocSettingsActivity.java:213)
        at com.psadi.psad.TSGS.LocSettingsActivity.checkPermission(LocSettingsActivity.java:172)
        at com.psadi.psad.TSGS.LocSettingsActivity.onCreate(LocSettingsActivity.java:53)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6860)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2674)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2782)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1521)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6228)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

My project Code is :

```
public class LocSettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback {

protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
protected LocationRequest locationRequest;
int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 100;
private AppPreferences mPrefs;
GPSTracker gps;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Step 1
    checkPermission();
    mPrefs  = AppPreferences.getAppPreferences(LocSettingsActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);
    PendingResult result =
            LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    builder.build()
            );

    result.setResultCallback(this);
    mPrefs  = AppPreferences.getAppPreferences(LocSettingsActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@Override
public void onResult(@NonNull Result locationSettingsResult) {
    final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
    switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

            // NO need to show the dialog;

            break;

        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
            //  Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog

            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                // in onActivityResult().

                status.startResolutionForResult(LocSettingsActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);

            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

                //failed to show
            }
            break;

        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
            // Location settings are unavailable so not possible to show any dialog now
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("PSAD", "..........GPS enabled..............");

            //TODO Important When Gps Enable Just Now Need Some Time ..........otherwise lat long 0.0 fetch
            // TODO Need Some time to call GPS Tracker Service
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);     //Todo dummy delay for 2 second
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    //update ui on UI thread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            callLocationGpsTracker();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }).start();


        } else {
            callLocationDialog();
            Log.e("PSAD", "..........GPS not enabled..............");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS is not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

}

private void checkPermission(){
    if (!hasGPSDevice(LocSettingsActivity.this)) {
        Log.e("PSAD", "Gps not Supported");
        Toast.makeText(LocSettingsActivity.this, "Gps not Supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Log.e("PSAD", "Gps Supported ---hasGPSDevice return true--Step 1 Pass...........");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LocSettingsActivity.this,
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA);

            if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Log.e("permission", "granted");
                locationEnabled_or_Not();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LocSettingsActivity.this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,}, 1);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Lower Than MarshMallow");
            locationEnabled_or_Not();
        }
    }
}


//TODO Step 1
public boolean hasGPSDevice(Context context) {
    final LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (mgr == null)
        return false;
    final List<String> providers = mgr.getAllProviders();
    if (providers == null)
        return false;
    return providers.contains(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
}


//TODO Step 2
// TODO When Location not enabled show popup
// TODO When Location already Enabled CAll GPS Tracker
private void locationEnabled_or_Not() {
    Log.e("PSAD", "locationEnabled_or_Not Step 2 Pass...........");
    final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) LocSettingsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (!manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && hasGPSDevice(LocSettingsActivity.this)) {
        Log.e("PSAD", "Gps not enabled");
        callLocationDialog();
    } else {
        Log.e("PSAD", "Gps already enabled");
        callLocationGpsTracker();           // TODO When Gps already enabled call direct GPS Tracker
    }
}

//TODO Step 3 when hasGPSDevice return true

private void callLocationDialog() {

    Log.e("PSAD", "callLocationDialog Step 3 Popup called ...........");

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);
}

//TODO Step 4 when location on fetch GPS Tracker Through Latitude Longitude

private void callLocationGpsTracker() {

    Log.e("PSAD", "callLocationGpsTracker Step 4 Called ... fetch Location");

    gps = new GPSTracker(LocSettingsActivity.this);

    // check if GPS enabled
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {

        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

        Log.e("MainActivity", "latitude -> " + latitude);
        Log.e("MainActivity", "longitude -> " + longitude);

        getAddress(latitude, longitude);


    } else {
        // TODO can't get location
        // TODO GPS or Network is not enabled
        // TODO Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings

        //TODO need again call Locaton Dialog
        callLocationDialog();
    }
}

private void getAddress(double lat, double lon) {
    String cityName = "";
    String stateName = "";
    String postalCode = "";
    String countryName = "";

    StringBuilder finalAddress = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(LocSettingsActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);

        if (addresses != null) {

            try {
                cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                stateName = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                countryName = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
                postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();

                if (cityName != null)
                    mPrefs.putStringValue(AppPreferences.CITY, cityName);

                if (addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) != null)
                    finalAddress.append(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                if (addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) != null)
                    finalAddress.append(" " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1));
                if (addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2) != null)
                    finalAddress.append(" " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));
                if (addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(3) != null)
                    finalAddress.append(" " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(3));

                Log.e("PSAD", "addres 0   ->  " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0));
                Log.e("PSAD", "addres 1   ->  " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1));
                Log.e("PSAD", "addres 2   ->  " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2));
                Log.e("PSAD", "addres 3   ->  " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(3));
                Log.e("PSAD", "addres final   ->  " + finalAddress);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("PSAD", "Exception occurd    ->  " + e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.e("PSAD", "cityName   ->  " + cityName);
            Log.e("PSAD", "stateName ->  " + stateName);
            Log.e("PSAD", "countryName ->  " + countryName);
            Log.e("PSAD", "PostalCode ->  " + postalCode);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkPermission();
}
```

The error line which seems to be causing problems is:

```
mPrefs.putStringValue(AppPreferences.CITY, cityName);
```

Comment: call `checkPermission();` after `mPrefs  = AppPreferences.getAppPreferences(LocSettingsActivity.this);`

Answer (score 0):

Just put `mPrefs = AppPreferences.getAppPreferences(LocSettingsActivity.this);`

before `checkPermission();`

Like this

```
mPrefs = AppPreferences.getAppPreferences(LocSettingsActivity.this);
checkPermission();
```

Comment: you can mark it as correct